# LED/Resistor set up for a model display

Tags: led, resistors, series, model

I am currently making a scaled model display that uses 16 LED in a series and I would like to wire it up to be on one switch, so I need a single power supply to connect them to.  I have various different colors that I would like to use in the display.  I have 6 red LED (2.0v), 6 white LED (3.2v), and 4 yellow (2.0v) so a total of 36 volts.  I would like to know what resistor or resistors I need to use for my power supply which is 48v (it is the closest I could find to 36v).  Please provide me with any insight that could help this process as I have been tinkering with it for about a week with only burn marks on my table to show for it (when I added the wrong resistor types).

Thank you for anyone's quick reply.

Comment: Why do you want them to be in series?

Comment: The problem with them will in series is that they will all receive the same current. However, the different colors will have different perceived brightnesses. You will not be able to control them separately.

Comment: (Vsupply-Vf)/R=I. What current are they rated at?

Comment: -Spehro Pefhany: I don't need them to be in a series, but I have tried to put them into a parallel connection, but I would blow them whenever I would try to power it with and the 48v power supply and would only power half when using the 24v power supply.   From my research to parallel them with the 48v I would need a nearly 15v resistor to power it.

Comment: -Doxylover:  I don't need to control them separately, I just want to plug it into the wall with a single plug and not have multiple plugs for each of the different sets of lights.  Thanks you for any support or help to make this happen.

Comment: -Winny: I don't know exactly what they are rated, the only numbers I know are the voltage for each color and that they have a current of 20mA.  I know you provided a formula to determine but I don't understand directly, please let me know and I will figure out the calculations to help out in any way.